# Obtaining PayPal Partner ID for Onboarding API

Tags: paypal

I'm using paypal commerce platform to onboard sellers.
Sellers are onboarded successfully and a merchant-id is generated after process is completed.

but when I'm trying to fetch their information from the following api (as provided by paypal docs),

**[https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/partners/{partner-id}/merchant-integrations/{merchant-id}](https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/partners/%7Bpartner-id%7D/merchant-integrations/%7Bmerchant-id%7D)**

I'm confused what is the merchant-id and what is partner-id, I only get merchantId after seller is onboarded. there is no partner-id

And Wow, look at their docs.
[please see the doc image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TChmT.png)

Partner id is refernenced as merchant account id.

what the heck is this.
If any body could help me. please it would be much appriciated. Please ignore the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling partner APIs, you are the partner. Obtain your account's ID from the place explained in the doc image you linked, under Profile and settings.

For sandbox mode you'll need to log into the sandbox API calling partner account via the https://www.sandbox.paypal.com account interface -- using its credentials from the [Developer Dashboard](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts).

Comment: Thank you!! omg this is very confusing from PayPal's side. Why would a fake account be needed for such a key